# Problem with cartesian to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm trying to find the volume of the interior solid of the cylinders $y^2=2x$, $x^2+y^2=4x$, under the plane $x+z=5$ and above $z=0$.

Which the integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\sqrt{2x}}^{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}\int_{0}^{5-x} dzdydx= 6\pi-\frac{224}{15}$$

But it's difficult to calculate, so i want to change it to cylindrical coordinates, but i can't find the right $r$ to make the integral.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_?^?\int_0^{5-r\cos(\theta)}rdzdrd\theta$$

Comment: I'm not sure in cyindrical coordinates the problem simplifies.

Comment: Although the circle $x^2+y^2=4x$ looks very nice in polar coordinates ($r=4\cos\theta$), the parabola $y^2=2x$ is sort of awkward. You would have to split it up into $0\le|\theta|\le \pi/4$ and $\pi/4\le |\theta|\le \pi/2$, anyhow. However, I don't think your cartesian integral is right. Doesn't it go to $x=4$? When $0\le x\le 2$, we have $|y|\le \sqrt{2x}$, and when $2\le x\le 4$, we have $|y|\le\sqrt{4x-x^2}$.  I don't think your limits describe "interior" to both cylinders.

Comment: I guess I take it back. $r=2\cot\theta$ isn't so awkward. The problem needs to be split into two integrals, either way.